# Pass custom fields to Active Campaign Api

Tags: c#-4.0, idictionary

Hi I am using following code to add contact to Active Campaign api (http://www.activecampaign.com/).
The contact gets added however the custom field "%ISTRIAL%" is always blank.
Can someone please let me know what is wrong with follwoing:

```
 var result = await client.ApiAsync("contact_add", new Dictionary<string, string>
 {
     {"email", emailAddress},
     {"first_name",  FirstName},
     {"last_name", LastName},
     {"phone", phoneNumber},
     {"orgname", companyName},
     {"list[2]", "{%ISTRIAL%=yes}"}
 });
```

Comment: Did you forget a few tags, or, lacking those, links?  We don't know what "Active Campaign API" is.  At the least, you want to add the plain "c#" tag since most people probably don't follow "c#-4.0".  You won't get a lot of attention with that.

Comment: What do you see if you edit "list[2]" to 'p[2]' and for the custom field create a new row {"ISTRIAL", yes} ?

Comment: @malditojavi , if I change to 'p[2]' the response says "List ID 0 does not exist"

Comment: @max -- if you had taken my advice, you would probably have over 30 views by now and probably an answer or two.  Instead you only have 8 views, but your question is like water under a bridge -- even if you tag it correctly now, it won't be on the top of peoples lists because it's over an hour old.

Comment: @max - The list ID would depend on your list, likely we can help further on this from help@activecampaign.com if you drop us a line there with your account name